# Why does my application crash when calling an Excel 2016 file through ShellExecute?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell, excel-2016

Why does my application crash when calling an Excel 2016 file through ShellExecute?

Minimal example:

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
   CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
   int nRetCode = (int)ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, _T("c:\\temp\\MyExcel.xlsx"), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

- It only crashes on an Excel 2016 .xlsx file.
- Same code works on Excel 2013 .xlsx file (ie. with only Excel 2013 installed 
  that is).
- Same code works on an Excel 2016 .xls file (with Excel 2016 installed)
- Same code works on an Excel 2016 .xlsx file when name is changed to a .xls file (with Excel 2016 installed)
- Excel is installed using ClickToRun (I think this is the only way it can be installed)

From event viewer:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-10-22T15:22:13.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>3393</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>xxx.se</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>ShellExecuteTest.exe</Data>
    <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>5628ff16</Data>
    <Data>msoshext.dll</Data>
    <Data>16.0.4229.1029</Data>
    <Data>56067af7</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>00078e8c</Data>
    <Data>e8c</Data>
    <Data>01d10cdd6d71246d</Data>
    <Data>C:\xxx\ShellExecuteTest.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\Office16\msoshext.dll</Data>
    <Data>ab37d64c-78d0-11e5-8261-005056ae16e5</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Check the error from the Event Viewer. There is something special with C2R installation of Excel 2016. The original example (not shown here) has been in use for around 18 years with Excel 97 up to Excel 2013. Only C2R installed Excel 2016 is the problem.

Comment: Does it crash when run from the ebugger ?

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry that I cannot test if the problem occurs in the debugger. I have tested our real world program at different sites to confirm the problem. Then I made the hello-world mini-example and tested this in a VM with Excel 2016 installed. I have had it installed on my developer station for debugging an Outlook 2016 problem but the whole suit was to buggy for production so I had it removed. In a worst case scenario I will have to reinstall it again. Was hoping for community input first. I imagine it either to be a Excel bug or some kind of registry problem.

Comment: Is there another way of executing the file instead of ShellExecute? CreateProcess should fail the same way I imagine (not tested thou).

Comment: Go ahead and test `CreateProcess`. However for `CreateProcess' you must provide Excel's .exe file and not an directly .xlsx file. The latter must be put in the commande line parametr (see CreateProcess documentation).

Comment: Very interesting... CreateProcess does work. (But it is a pain to find excel.exe installation location, on test computer it is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16 )

Comment: Another thing that does work (but is undesirable, since we don't want a DOS-window appearing) is `_tsystem(_T("c:\xxx\MyExcelFile.xlsx"));`